# Using split function to split LHS and RHS and store in each of variable accordingly

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, split

May i know why the "a" and "b" variables only store the last element of the for loop data instead of the full for loop data?

```
listofinfo = ["a=1","b=2","c=3","d=4","e=5"]

for line in listofinfo:
    a,b = line.split("=")

print ("LHS:"+a)
print ("RHS:"+b)
```

`output--> LHS:e` # Expected output LHS:a,b,c,d,e

`output--> RHS:5` # Expected output RHS:1,2,3,4,5

The purpose of this code is to split the "=" between the alphabet & the number. after that, all the alphabet will store inside the variable "a" which is LHS and number will store in the variable "b" which is RHS. May i know what mistake i have made in above code?

Update:
I try to play around and modify the code below like that:

```
myDictionary = {}
for line in listofinfo:
    a, b = line.split("=")
    myDictionary['a'] = b

for element in myDictionary:
    print (element, myDictionary[element])
```

Surprisingly, it only print out something like this --> ('a', '5')

In my understanding, within the for loop, just like what list do, it will append the content into the dictionary right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` and `b` are assigned each element *in succession*. You only print the last values. If you moved your `print` statements *into the loop* you'd see each output:

```
for line in listofinfo:
    a, b = line.split("=")

    print "LHS:" + a
    print "RHS:" + b
```

If you wanted to create two separate lists of values, then do so explicitly:

```
a_list = []
b_list = []
for line in listofinfo:
    a, b = line.split("=")
    a_list.append(a)
    b_list.append(b)

print "LHS:", ','.join(a_list)
print "RHS:", ','.join(b_list)
```

Comment: Thank You. It's works. Let me to digest why the join function is needed. Will reply again later...thanks.

Comment: @Pi-Turn: the `str.join()` is only used to produce the output you specified; you could just use `print "LHS:", a_list` and see the list representation instead.

Comment: Thanks again. I only know to use the for loop to print out list previously. Now I learn the join function. Appreciate it...

Comment: could you please take a look at what i just updated in my question? I try to modify a bit to make it work for dictionary, but it does not work as what list is doing... is my understanding wrong?

Comment: I think i have solved the problem.. Thanks...
Minor mistake can bring the functionality gone...sorry about that